# Using babel-polyfill with grunt and browserify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, babeljs, polyfills

My grunt build system transpiles my javascript (which is using react as well).
Unfortunately it doesn't transpile Promises. For that, I need a polyfill.
I want to include babel-polyfill with my grunt build system.
My build system uses browserify along with babelify and the es2015 preset.

How do I include babel-polyfill into the mix?

Here is what I have...

**Inside gruntfile.js, here is where I use browserify**

```
browserify: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      watch: true,
      transform: [["babelify", {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}], ["envify", {NODE_ENV: 'development'}]]
    },
    files: {
      'dist/js/app.js' : 'src/js/main.js'
    }
  },
  build: {
    options: {
      transform: [["babelify", {presets: ['es2015', 'react'], compact: true }], ["envify", {NODE_ENV: 'production'}]]
    },
    files: {
      'dist/js/app.js' : 'src/js/main.js'
    }
  }
},
```

**Here is my babelrc file**

```
{
 "presets": [ "react", "es2015" ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that babel-polyfill is included as a dependency, at the top of your entry file 'src/js/main.js' add the line:

```
import "babel-polyfill";
```

No need to do anything in your GruntFile.js

Comment: Why do you think import will work with a grunt-builded system?

Comment: Babel polyfill is now deprecated. Use other polyfills.